# Help proving that the derivative $Df(x)$ is continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

In what follows, $X, Y$ are Banach and $U \subseteq X$ is open. Consider the map $f: U \to Y$. We say that $f$ is locally uniformly differentiable at $x \in U$ and $h \in X$ if given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ and an $\epsilon_{0} > 0$ such that:
$$\bigg{|}\bigg{|}\frac{f(y+th)-f(y)}{t} - \delta_{y}(h)\bigg{|}\bigg{|} < \epsilon $$
holds for every $y \in V$, $||h|| < 1$ and $|t| < \epsilon_{0}$.

I have to prove that if $f$ is locally uniformly continuous on $U$ then it is Fréchet differentiable on $U$ and its Fréchet derivative $Df(x) = \delta_{x}$ is continuous.

I already proved the first part, that is, that the Fréchet derivative exists and satisfies $Df(x) = \delta_{x}$. But I'm stuck at proving this derivative is continuous. I was trying to construct a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_{n} \to x$ and proving $||(Df(x_{n})-Df(x))h|| \le \epsilon ||h||$ for every $||h|| < 1$, but I got nowhere because $h$ and $x_{n}$ must be independent so I couldn't use the condition of the definition. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $\|x - y\|$ and $t$ is small enough, the vectors
\begin{align*}
f(x) - f(y) &- \delta_y(x - y),\\
f(x + th) - f(y) &- \delta_y(x + th - y),\\
f(x + th) - f(x) &- \delta_x(t h)
\end{align*}
are small. Now, you can combine these vectors to $(\delta_x - \delta_y)(h)$.

Comment: Very nice! I guess I proved the result using your hint, now. One minor observation: if you combine the vectors as you mentioned you will get $t(\delta_{x}-\delta_{y})(h)$, so according to my calculations you should take $||x-y||$ and $|t|$ small enough and, in particular, smaller than $||h|| < 1$ right? This way one gets $|t|||(\delta_{x}-\delta_{y})(h)|| \le \epsilon |t| ||h|| \le \epsilon ||h||$.

Comment: According to my (very rough) notes, we get $|(\delta_y-\delta_x)(h)| \le \epsilon(1 + \|x-y\|/t) \|h\|$, i.e., $\|\delta_y - \delta_x\| \le \epsilon(1+\|x-y\|/t)$. Thus, it is important to have $\|x-y\| \le t$.

Comment: Okay, apparently you did it a little different than me. I got curious on how you got the $||h||$ in the right hand side of the inequality. For instance, it seems that your answer's third relation led to something like $||f(x+th)-f(x)-\delta_{x}(th)|| \le \epsilon ||h||$ instead of $\le \epsilon t$. If this is correct, how did you get the $||h||$ instead of the $t$?

Comment: Did you use the fact that it is Fréchet differentiable?

Comment: No, sorry, there should not be a $\|h\|$.